# unable to create sharePoint workflow with email

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I recently started using sharepoint online. I faced a problem while sending emails through sharepoint designer workflow. But for some reason the alerts in the document library and/lists in the sharepoint online are working.

Comment: Hi @rinu you said "I faced a problem" ?! should you elaborate more your scenario

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. our organisation has moved away from on prem to sharepoint online and some of our admin has worked on it has left. Now i have been asked to create a workflow. I was able to create it and publish it but the part where the email action is in the workflow wont send email. I would appreciate any help with regards to solving  or debugging this problem or to know if the email is even configured in the sharepoint online.

Comment: does workflow status ends in completed status or any other status ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the email address updated in the user profile for that particular user. To isolate the issue you can use write to history option to write the user email ID in the history list. This way you can identify what email address is fetched by Workflow for sending an email and is it same as in UPA.